# maintaining counts of items in sortable lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-droppable

I need to maintain the exact counts of items in some sortable lists and am having trouble doing it. The moment I start dragging from list #1 that count increments and there is an extra item in play from then on. The moment I hover over list #2 it's count increments.

[Example, click for fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/3xnL7zko/2/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#ul1, #ul2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  });

function update_counts() {
    var n_ul1 = $("#ul1 li").length;
    var n_ul2 = $("#ul2 li").length;
    $("#count1").html(n_ul1);
    $("#count2").html(n_ul2);
}

$(function () {
    $("#ul2,#ul1").droppable({
        over: function (ev, ui) {
            update_counts();
        },
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            update_counts();
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall answer my own question:

```
function update_counts() {
    var n_ul1 = $("#ul1 li").not(".ui-sortable-helper").length;
    var n_ul2 = $("#ul2 li").not(".ui-sortable-helper").length;
    $("#count1").html(n_ul1);
    $("#count2").html(n_ul2);
}
```

.not(".ui-sortable-helper") is what was needed.

Comment: Please mark it as accept to indicate that the question is solved. don't leave it unanswered forever...

Comment: When you answer your own question you have to wait 2 days to be able to accept the answer.

Comment: I'll also add that, although the above solution makes the example, work beautifully in the app I'm working on .ui-sortable-helper is not the class that my dragged item has, it's .ui-state-default for some reason so it doesn't work there.